# How to show the framerate in PyQTgraph?

Tags: python, animation, opengl, frame-rate, pyqtgraph

I am doing some live data updating using some external hardware. I need to know the framerate of the animation, to know if the problem is my potato computer or the sampling rate of the hardware.

Is there a way to display the framerate in pyqtgraph?
i am using it in combination with openGL and am displaying a heatmap that changes live based on touch to the hardware. However i have the feeling it is lagging a bit.

I am imagining something inside the update.self routine.

My code is not really relevant, as it is working. I just need some (probably very obvious) way to read the update rate.

I already looked into realtime imaging, but it is not worth designing a multiple thread approach...

Answer (score 0):

This works somewhat, not sure if it does what i want...
I define in the start

```
   import datetime 
   def __init__(self):
     self.start_time=0
```

for the first loop.
And then i read the frame rate like this:

```
def update:

    #some code
    frames= datetime.datetime.now().time()
    frames=frames.second-self.start_time.second + (frames.microsecond-self.start_time.microsecond)/1000000
    print(1/frames)
    self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```